# JSON response with arraylist

Tags: java, ajax, json

I am new to JSON and jQuery and I want to get JSON data using AJAX. I want to show data using a submit button I try like this:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
List<Countries> country = new ArrayList<Countries>();
country = FetchData.getAllCountries();
JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(country);

// set the response content-type
response.setContentType("application/json");

// writing the json-array to the output stream
out.print(jsonArray);
out.flush();
```

I get a compile time error: `The constructor JSONArray(List<Countries>) is undefined`.
 below way i try it working but i want to implemt using jason array

```
           PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    ArrayList<Countries> country = new ArrayList<Countries>();
    country = FetchData.getAllCountries();
    String json = new Gson().toJson(country);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    out.write(json);
```

working below way

```
ArrayList<Countries> country=new ArrayList<Countries>();
country=FetchData.getAllCountries();
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(country, new TypeToken<List<Countries>>() {}.getType());

JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);
```

Comment: The error means JSONArray does not accept a List / or only a List in it's constructor.

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: arraylist response using jsaon array is possible or any other solution

Comment: json-simple-1.1.1.jar lib  used

Comment: Look what I found! https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples .... its the Wiki for that json library, it contains encoding examples. Check them out.

Answer (score 1):

Is that the json-simple library you're using? If it is:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
List<Countries> country = new ArrayList<Countries>();
country = FetchData.getAllCountries();
JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
js.put("countries", country); // make sure the Country class overrides toString()

// set the response content-type
response.setContentType("application/json");

// writing the json-array to the output stream
out.print(js.toJSONString());
out.flush();
```

You seem to be trying to insert an anonymous array into your json string. You can't do that, it's not valid JSON. For example, your JSON **cannot** look like:

```
{
    ["1st Country", "2nd Country", "3rd Country"]
}
```

...there needs to be at least one key/value pair in JSON e.g.

```
{
    "countries": ["1st Country", "2nd Country", "3rd Country"]
}
```

...so "countries" is the key and the array is the value. If you use the example code I gave above, then your server should return a JSON string to the browser that looks like the valid JSON example above. So, if your client javascript is calling the server using an AJAX call like this (using jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
    type:     'GET',
    url:      '/your-server-path',
    dataType: 'json',
    success:  function(response, status, request) {
        // jQuery automatically converts the JSON object to a Javascript object 
        for (int i=0; i<response.countries.length; i++) {
            console.log("Country " + i + " is " + response.countries[i]);
        }
    }, 
    error: function(request, status, error) {
        console.log("Something went wrong...");
    }
});
```

Also, as I mentioned in the first code snippet, you must override the `toString()` method of your `Country` class, so that each `Country` instance can be converted to a string and added to the JSON array e.g.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // return some combination of variables in your Country class
    // or however you want a Country to be represented
}
```

Comment: client side which way to set resopnse    because above way implmenting got error errror (object object)

Comment: ArrayList<Countries> country=new ArrayList<Countries>();
 country=FetchData.getAllCountries();
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(country, new TypeToken<List<Countries>>() {}.getType());

 JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
 response.setContentType("application/json");
 response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);

Answer (score 0):

From the Wiki for json-simple https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_2-4_-_Encode_a_JSON_array_-_Using_List_and_streaming

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
list.add("foo");
list.add(new Integer(100));
list.add(new Double(1000.21));
list.add(new Boolean(true));
list.add(null);
StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
JSONValue.writeJSONString(list, out);
String jsonText = out.toString();
System.out.print(jsonText);
```

So yours would be

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
List<Countries> country = new ArrayList<Countries>();
country = FetchData.getAllCountries();
JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(country);

StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
JSONValue.writeJSONString(country, out);

// set the response content-type
response.setContentType("application/json");

// writing the json-array to the output stream
out.print(out.toString());
out.flush();
```